# Left, right, and setw together for output problem

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How can I make this:

```cpp
cout << right << setw(8) << showTime + " PM" << setw(13) << right << name << endl;
```

Print like this:

```
_8:00 PM_____________Mark Finch`
```

So it's like this in a column:

```
_8:00 PM_____________Mark Finch
_9:00 PM_____________Mark Bob
11:00 PM_____________Mars Bobinas
```

I'm wrong, but I just don't understand it please help...

Comment: After "print like this" should be an "instead of this". That is, show both the expected and actual result, not just the expected.

Comment: Use the `std::setfill('_')` manipulator to change the padding character to underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to print 13 spaces followed by the name:

```
cout << right << setw(8) << showTime + " PM" << setw(13) << " " << setw(1) << name << endl;
```

Note that you need to reset width back to 1 to avoid padding inside the name.